# Unable to get toastr to work in my mvc application

Tags: jquery, toast

I am trying to use toastr in my mvc application. When I downloaded from Nuget I found the two files
added to my scripts folder

```
    toastr.js
    toastr.min.js
```

I added the .js file to my layout page

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/toastr.js"></script>
```

I now wrote the code below in my layout page in the scripts section. 
when I run my application, nothing happens. Am I missing something please?

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

            displayToastr();

        });

        function displayToastr() {
            //alert('yes');
            // Display a info toast, with no title
            toastr.info('Hi Mahedee, This information for you.');

            // Display a warning toast, with no title
            toastr.warning('Hi Mahedee, This the first warning for you!');

            // Display a success toast, with a title
            toastr.success('Yes! You have successfully completed your task!', 'Congratulation for you, Mahedee!');

            // Display an error toast, with a title
            toastr.error('An error occured in the solution!', 'Please contact with system administrator.');
        }
```

Comment: Here is my solution. I was missing the css file and when I added it everything began to work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Are you sure your JS paths are OK and that you run your code after loading those js libs ?

Comment: Yes I did. It is not working. It should be an easy thing I guess. I have the links at the begining of my layout page. Do they need to be at the end?

Comment: Please create a fiddle for this or provide a working code sample - full HTML that is. I made a quick one locally using CDN sources and it worked ...